# Why does the Function App running on .net5 reports a missing / empty service bus connection string?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, .net-5

I have an Function App running on `.net5` running on Linux. One of the Function is bound to a service bus, like this:

```
[Function("v1-on-send-invitation-email")]
public async Task OnSendInvitationEmailAsync
(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("emails", Connection = "ConnectionString")]
    string requestMessage
)
{
  ...
}
```

The `ConnectionString` setting is defined in the `local.settings.json`:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
        "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "53515112-9f0f-4d88-88ac-cf371ad1597c",
        "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~3",
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=XXXX",

        "ServiceBusConfiguration__ConnectionString": "Endpoint=XXXX",
        "ConnectionString": "Endpoint=XXXX"
    },
    "Host": {
        "LocalHttpPort": 7072,
        "CORS": "*"
    }
}
```

However, if I change the binding to use the other setting `ServiceBusConfiguration__ConnectionString`, it does not work anymore:

```
[Function("v1-on-send-invitation-email")]
    public async Task OnSendInvitationEmailAsync
    (
        [ServiceBusTrigger("emails", Connection = "ServiceBusConfiguration__ConnectionString")]
        string requestMessage
    )
    {
      ...
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
A host error has occurred during startup operation '9f9d261a-61d8-4d87-95bd-02bfe48ed1b3'.
[2021-09-04T11:53:41.851Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus: Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK ServiceBus connection string 'ServiceBusConfiguration__ConnectionString' is missing or empty.
```

**Question**

Why does the service bus binding fail knowing the connection string is *not* missing or empty?

**Update**

The reason I am using `__` is because this setting is injected via `IOptions` in the code. I am also running on Linux. Here is the class that get the setting:

```
internal sealed class ServiceBusConfiguration
{
   public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

   public string EmailsQueueName { get; set; }        
}
```

This is why I have the duplicated setting in the `local.settings.json` file and I would like to avoid the duplication.

Comment: Could it be because `__` is a special thing in reading .Net configuration settings? Can you try by specifying the setting name like `ServiceBusConfigurationConnectionString`?

Comment: Or specify the Service Bus connection string like `"ServiceBusConfiguration": {"ConnectionString": "Endpoint=XXXX"}`.

Comment: @GauravMantri It looks like the __ is the issue but I do not understand why it can't work with it. Maybe something special needs to be done to make it work...

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I believe when the configuration gods in .Net sees `__`, they try to parse it and create a JSON object out of it. That's why we always specify configuration as objects in settings.json file but with `__` in application configuration settings in Azure Portal.

Comment: @GauravMantri That could explain it; it makes me believe that the ConnectionString property is not to be interpreted as a 'simple' string, like the [docs would suggest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.webjobs.servicebustriggerattribute.connection?view=azure-dotnet-preview): 'Gets or sets the app setting name that contains the Service Bus connection string'